# VueJS process component or HTML using a function

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I understand how this works from the [VueJS Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Base-Example):

```
<div id="components-demo">
 <button-counter></button-counter>
</div>
```

And also this:

```
<div id="app">
  <a v-on:click="loadElement(request, etc)">Load</a>
</div>
```

Is there any way to write the equivalent from a function and have Vue pick it up?  For example as this:

```
<div id="app">
  {{ writeComponent('component-name', etc) }}
  or
  {{ writeElement('loadElement') }} <!-- which then writes the component above -->
</div>
```

The reason for this is that in this context quite a few components might need to be written and writing it out in HTML would be cumbersome.

Comment: [Render functions](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html) are probably what you're looking for.

Comment: You are probably right but I am trying to find an example that addresses this; also I have come across this: https://jsfiddle.net/chrisvfritz/b2qj69o1/, but being able to dynamically output components or "bound" html inside mustache braces would be the ideal

Answer (score 1):

You could use the render function like below:

```js
Vue.component('button-counter', {
  template: '<span class="bc">bc</span>'
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    request: 'req!',
    etc: 'etc!',
    buttonCounters: []
  },
  methods: {
    loadElement(r, e) {
      console.log('loadElement', r, e);
      this.buttonCounters.push(r);
    }
  },
  render(h) {
    let bcs = this.buttonCounters.map(bc => h('button-counter'));
    
    let loadLink = h('a', {on: {"click": ($event) => { this.loadElement(this.request, this.etc)}}}, ["Load"]);

    return h('div', {attrs: {"id": "app"}}, [loadLink, " ", ...bcs])
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Though the same can be achieved via regular template and `v-for`:

```js
Vue.component('button-counter', {
  template: '<span class="bc">bc</span>'
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    request: 'req!',
    etc: 'etc!',
    buttonCounters: []
  },
  methods: {
    loadElement(r, e) {
      console.log('loadElement', r, e);
      this.buttonCounters.push(r);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
 <a v-on:click="loadElement(request, etc)">Load</a>
 <button-counter v-for="(bc, index) in buttonCounters" :key="index"></button-counter>
</div>
```